# Which feature descriptors to use and why?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, sift, object-detection

I do like to do compute the position and orientation of a camera in a civil aircraft cockpit.

I do use LEDs as fixed points. My plan is to save their X,Y,Z Position associated with the LED.

How can I detect and identify my LEDs on my images? Which feature descriptor and feature point extractor should I use?

How should I modify my image prior to feature detection?

I like to stay efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**----Please stop voting this question down----**
Now after having found the solution to my problem, I do realize the question might have been too generic.
Anyways to support other people googeling I am going to describe my answer.

With combinations of OpenCVs functions I create masks which contain areas where the LEDs could be in white. The rest of the image is black. These functions are for example Core.range, Imgproc.dilate, and Imgproc.erode. Also with Imgproc.findcontours I am filtering out too large or too small contours. Also used to combine masks is Core.bitwise_and, or Core.bitwise_not.
The masks are computed from an image in the HSV color space as input.

Having these masks with potential LED areas, I do compute color histograms, which of the intensity normalized rgb colors. (Hue did not work well enough for me). These histograms are trained and normalized using a set of annotated input images and represent my descriptor.

I do match the trained descriptor against computed onces in the application using histogram intersection.

So I receive distance measures. Using a threshold for these measures, the measures and the knowledge of the geometric positions of the real-life LEDs I translate the patches to a graph system, which helps me to find the longest chain of potential LEDs.
[image]
[image]
[image]